# PCB connector identification

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, automotive

appreciate if anyone is able to help to identify this connector in the photo below.

Basically i am trying to identify different types of connectors/ports around different PCB to find debug ports.

thank you in advance! :)

edit: dimensions
length: 5mm
width: 12mm

additional info: this connector seem to be used in automotive tcu

[image]

Comment: It would help if you provided the dimensions of the connector.

Comment: oops sorry, added dimensions @RonBeyer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a Hirose [DF20F-20DP-1V(56)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF20F-20DP-1V-56/H10727CT-ND/1026445)
this image shows with the pick and place cap in place, however appears to be the one.

[image]

Here is a link to the drawing. https://www.hirose.com/product/download/?distributor=digikey&type=2d&lang=en&num=DF20F-20DP-1V(56)